# Slow down iOS animation to debug?

Tags: ios, debugging, animation

On OS X, one can hold the shift key to cause animation to slow down. Is there some way to apply this to iOS via a remote debugger or in Instruments?

(Alternatively, I *could* record in QuickTime and replay frame by frame, but I would rather not have to do that.)

EDIT: I'm looking for a way to do this on the device.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can slow down animations in your iOS Simulator by clicking Debug-->Toogle Slow Animations in frontmost app.

Comment: Looking for a way to do this on the device.

Comment: I guess there's no simple way of doing something like that on the device without touching the animation itself.

Comment: That's interesting... So I wonder if there's a way to swizzle something in the animation stack...

Comment: Swizzling could work. What about just increasing the animation length in your code?

Comment: I would try to swizzle the system level animation calls. Slow down the whole thing.

Comment: yeah often the solution is just so simple :-).

Answer (score 3):

Temporarily set `layer.speed` on the view you are animating to a value less than one. For example in my UIViewController subclass, I have a UIView subclass which is animating some changes to it's subviews. If I want to slow down those animations (and only those, not other transitions):

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController {
    private let myView = MyView()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // slow down animation speed for only this view
        myView.layer.speed = 0.1
    }
}
```

If you want to slow down all animations in your app, set `window?.layer.speed`, for example in your `AppDelegate`.

Don't forget to remove this code once you're done perfecting your animation!

Answer (score 1):

Select the simulator and use ⌘T

You will get an output in the console telling you if it's been turned on or off.